# Multithreading with Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to develop simple Multi-threading Application in Android. Here is my code below:

```
package com.sudarshan.mythread;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {

EditText t;
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    int n = 8; // Number of threads
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        Thread object = new Thread(new MainActivity());
        object.start();
        t.setText(buffer.toString());
    }
}
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        // Displaying the thread that is running


        buffer.append ("Thread " +
                Thread.currentThread().getId() +
                " is running");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Throwing an exception
        showMessage("Error","Error Message");
    }
}
public void showMessage(String title,String Message)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
} }
```

And am trying to display data in stringbuffer buffer.The data should be appended in Stringbuffer everytime a thread is run.But nothing is shown via edit text.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Replace `new MainActivity` with `this`.

Comment: Thanks.Btw why this is required? This is used when you need to refer to own class's instance.Here the class is MainActivity.

Comment: Because this Activitie's `run` method has to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written `t.setText(buffer.toString());` immediately after threads have been started. But by that time, the buffer might not have been updated. So, update the `EditText` after the buffer is updated.

```
buffer.append ("Thread " +
            Thread.currentThread().getId() +
            " is running");
// Note: If you want to update UI from background thread, you should do it the following way.
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        t.setText(buffer.toString());
    }
});
```

Also, as @Bek stated, you should replace `new MainActivity()` with `this`.

Comment: the code works. Btw why this is required? This is used when you need to refer to own class's  instance.Here the class is MainActivity.

Comment: `this` means the current object. Since you want to update the `StringBuffer` and `EditText` of current activity, you should pass `this` instead of creating a new object of the activity. If you create and pass a new object, the buffer and editText of that new object tries to get updated. You may even get a `NullPointerException` since the `EditText` is not initialized in the new object.